# Is WebSphere Application Server v 7.0 compatible with the MQ v 6.0.2.8?

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

All,

Could some one tell me whether WebSphere Application Server v 7.0 is compatible with WebSphere MQ v 6.0.2.8?

We have upgraded our WAS 6 to WAS 7 version but we are unable to access MQ queues (v 6.0.2.8)

We got the below error message

```
com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession run WMSG0036E: Maximum message delivery retry count of 5 reached for MDB.........
```

Let me know what will be the solution for this.

---

Thanks for your inputs Manglu. Now I am confident that there should not be a compatibility issue for having WAS 7 + MQ 6 on Solaris 9. IBM website also says the this combination is supportable.

[IBM Web Page 1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27006263#notes)

[IBM Web Page 2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&context=SSFKSJ&dc=DB540&uid=swg21316899&loc=en_US&cs=UTF-8&lang=en&rss=ct171websphere)

So the main challenge for me to find out the proper configuration.

Any more inputs on this configuration would be more helpful.

Yes, the MQ 6 is at the end of service life however the MQ 6 upgrade is considered in the pipeline but at the moments we are trying to make WAS 7 works with MQ 6.

Comment: First thing to see is why is the message being rolled back to the queue. The stack should tell you the root cause for this.Please refer to the infocenter for configuration - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftmj_admrm.html

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere MQ 6.x is supported till 3Q 2012 - See [WebSphere MQ Lifecycle](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/websphere/support/lifecycle/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading this support article (TroubleShooting: Java Message Service (JMS) problems for WebSphere Application Server): 
Especially answer number 10
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21230514

For information which Websphere MQ client is shipped with WAS please check this link:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21248089

Answer (score 0):

"***retry count of 5 reached for MDB***" simply means that the infrastructure tried to deliver a message to an MDB and it failed 5 times (which is configured). It does not necessarily imply that there is a WMB and WAS compatibility issue.

If the MDB threw an exception that results in a transaction rollback then WAS as the runtime would do this.

AFAIK, there is no list of supported WMQ versions for WAS. I would be surprised if there is any compatibility issue here.

Considering the version that you are using V6.0.x, you should also consider that it is pretty close to its EOS (end of support).

Refer to this URL below. It is worth your time to ensure that your products are at supported levels (else you might struggle with getting support from IBM via the PMR route)

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?psynkey=H944813A36719U27&synkey=S859027D64278G42&synkey=D470946Y91234U77&synkey=I808682L89813Q29&synkey=S227352N29830F17&synkey=L299371Z29550D83&synkey=J486923J84636A67&synkey=J354129A85202S52&synkey=G553641J03597C44&synkey=K114857Z31565W24&synkey=M785400O15541W62&synkey=K901574F23938I87&synkey=D014927F09970A52&synkey=B921005A18964Q58&synkey=G997791B42373G83&synkey=C404143P70576O77&synkey=B732176N00835Y11&synkey=O962460O71397H42&synkey=K294119Z81378A99&synkey=L535466Q68603M11&synkey=R612721K44006J48&synkey=I485613C06060Q32&synkey=D056591Y43342B68&synkey=D625856W40756Y89&synkey=R661647T11156R19&synkey=Y154113J19416Y94&synkey=Q139640Z10567N72&synkey=U724929E41070R54&synkey=H684983Q27047Y83&synkey=T752290O95822U03&synkey=K579831E99893P56&synkey=F169175W36292M34&synkey=U252377D32013J71&synkey=O810806H21305N25&synkey=K962846I46319I65&synkey=S099150Z44584R20&synkey=R581372Y29152C07&synkey=R176858V96794Z68&from=spf